# Can't add any items to cart on bestbuy.ca but bestbuy.com works?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying to learn how to add items to my cart on BestBuy.ca. Unfortunately, whenever I attempt to add an item to my cart I get the following error:
[image]

However, on the American version of the site, the exact same code (only modified classname) succeeds at adding items to the cart. Anyone know why this is happening?

Canadian site code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

PATH = "C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/product/glue-loca-liquid-for-smart-phone-top-glass-lcd-screen-repairing-50g-optical-clear/10754680")

buyButton = driver.find_element_by_class_name("addToCartButton")
buyButton.click()

time.sleep(20)
```

American site code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

PATH = "C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.bestbuy.com/site/artscase-tempered-glass-screen-protector-for-apple-iphone-12-pro-max-clear/6442159.p?skuId=6442159")

##Will ask which bestbuy site if you're not American so added 10s sleep to select the American site.
time.sleep(10)

buyButton = driver.find_element_by_class_name("add-to-cart-button")
buyButton.click()

time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: If you look in the network requests, you can see that: Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www.bestbuy.ca/api/basket/v2/baskets" on this server. Which probably means that you have to access the site with a canada ip.

Comment: @art_architect Hmm that's odd, I have an IP from Canada and can add items to my cart when using my normal browser but can't add anything using webdriver.

Comment: I see... there is a restriction but not based on the ip. See below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bot detection feature based on navigator.webdriver.
You have to hide it using a chrome option, so that the site doesn't detect that the browser is started by an automation process.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

import time

PATH = "C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe"

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH,options=options)
driver.get("https://www.bestbuy.com/site/artscase-tempered-glass-screen-protector-for-apple-iphone-12-pro-max-clear/6442159.p?skuId=6442159")

##Will ask which bestbuy site if you're not American so added 10s sleep to select the American site.
time.sleep(10)

buyButton = driver.find_element_by_class_name("add-to-cart-button")
buyButton.click()

time.sleep(20)
```

### Without the chrome option flag:

[image]

### With the chrome option flag:

[image]

Comment: Interesting, is this a common flag to add or did you debug it somehow?

Comment: Debug, trial by error until i found what restriction is being used. I usually go from ip> user agent > to the webdriver detection.

Comment: Was just running into this same error and found this post. I think Bestbuy.ca updated their server as selenium now is blocked when I try this. bummer!

Comment: @bajan I just tried it, it works as described by art_architect

Comment: @Bajan Thanks a lot, I was searching this for 3 days continuously but didn't found anything. This solution works exactly as required. Can you drop a link all add_arguments commands so that it would be easy for implementation as per scenario.