# How to click add to cart button in selenium using python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

This is my code and it works completely fine for selecting size but it does not click the add to cart button as I can not see the product being added to my cart.

```
 from selenium import webdriver as wd
 import chromedriver_binary
 from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
 wd= wd.Chrome()
 action= ActionChains(wd)
 wd.implicitly_wait(1)
 url="https://www.nike.com/ca/launch/t/air-max-pre-day-pure-platinum"
 wd.get(url)
 #wd.maximize_window()
 size=wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/section[1]/div[2]/aside/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[15]/button')
 size.click()
 wd.implicitly_wait(1)
 cart=wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/section[1]/div[2]/aside/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/button')
 action.move_to_element(cart)
 action.click()
 action.perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

do not comment this :

```
#wd.maximize_window()
```

you are using absolute xpaths, which seems to be locating the right element, I would suggest you to write relative xpath and with Expected conditions :

and you need to scroll also  :

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 250)")
```

and then do this :

```
size=wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/section[1]/div[2]/aside/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[15]/button')
 size.click()
```

**Update 1 :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.nike.com/ca/launch/t/air-max-pre-day-pure-platinum")
sleep(10)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 750)")
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//figure[contains(@data-qa,'card-product-image-3')]")))).perform()
action.move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//figure[contains(@data-qa,'card-product-image-5')]")))).perform()
action.move_to_element(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='US 10.5']")))).click().perform()
action.move_to_element(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='add to bag']")))).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: When i maximise the window i get an error:                                                                  
          Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (1157, 911)

Comment: Check out the updated code under the update code 1 section

Comment: It still does not add to cart. Im really confused as to why it is only happening for the add to cart button. Could there be an image on top? I can not see any tho.

Comment: no, even for me also there's no image, looks like issue with the application. I tried execute_script and double click also. But the thing is even if you click manually nothing happens

Comment: It does work manually. https://www.nike.com/ca/launch/t/air-max-pre-day-pure-platinum  Click on the link choose a size and add to bag and it will show you that there is 1 product in the bag. Also as we can only add this shoe in our bag once per session could we use a loop and keep clicking?

Comment: No I meant if you click on it when windows is opened by selenium, it doesn't get clicked

Comment: You're not using headers as well as arguments in your code, Some websites block bots for performing tasks. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66312330/cant-add-any-items-to-cart-on-bestbuy-ca-but-bestbuy-com-works
Visit this post you'll find what you're looking for. IT worked for me

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:-

```
cart = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[text()='add to bag']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", cart)
cart.click()
```

Comment: Does not work like does not give me any error but just doesnt add the product to cart

Comment: are you selecting size before clicking on the button?

Comment: Yes first the size then adding it to bag